# Accessing a multidimensional params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in Rails (via rails c)

```
params[:user_employee_attributes_groups]
```

Which returns the following

```
(rdb:1) params[:user_employee_attributes_groups]
{"0"=>{"group_id"=>"2", "percentage_time"=>"30"}, "1"=>{"group_id"=>"3", "percentage_time"=>"20"}, "2"=>{"group_id"=>"1", "percentage_time"=>"50"}}
```

And I would like to access say index 0 to retrieve its respect group_id and percentage_time values.

I tried doing

```
params[:user_employee_attributes_groups[0]]
```

OR

```
params[:user_employee_attributes_groups["0"]]
```

None of them are acceptable.

What should the correct format?

Comment: if `params` is a Hash then you can try `params[:user_employee_attributes_groups]["0"]`

Comment: Thanks @arivarasan.  That's precisely what I need! It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `params[:user_employee_attributes_groups]["0"]`

Comment: There's an missing "]" in your code above.  It says syntax error.